Como configurar y conectar Azure Communication Services con Laravel?
Estoy trabajando en la integración de Azure Communication Services Email para Laravel, tengo por supuesto la cuenta creada, el dominio agregado, el SPF y DKIM validados, pasado esto agregar en mi config/services.php
 'azure' => [
        'endpoint' => env('AZURE_ENDPOINT'),
        'accessKey' => env('AZURE_ACCESS_KEY'),
    ]

para poder usar las credenciales que agrego al .env que en este caso es algo asi a modo de ejemplo:
#Configuration using Azure Communications Services for Email
AZURE_ENDPOINT=https://laravel.unitedstates.communication.azure.com
AZURE_ACCESS_KEY=Ie2zAasb56t4ht86u7axRLh

luego de esto he creado un servicio para la conexion
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

class AzureEmailService
{
    protected $client;
    protected $endpoint;
    protected $accessKey;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client();
        $this->endpoint = config('services.azure.endpoint');
        $this->accessKey = config('services.azure.accessKey');
    }

    public function sendEmail($to, $subject, $body)
    {
        $url = "{$this->endpoint}/emails:send?api-version=2021-10-01-preview";
        //dd($url);

        $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->accessKey,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ];

        $payload = [
            'senderAddress' => 'DoNotReply@mywebsite.com', //dirección de envío
            'recipients' => [
                'to' => [
                    ['address' => $to], // la API
                ],
            ],
            'content' => [
                'subject' => $subject,
                'plainText' => $body, // Cambia aquí si quiero usar HTML
                ],
        ];

        try {
            $response = $this->client->post($url, [
                'headers' => $headers,
                'json' => $payload,
            ]);

            return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            \Log::error('Error al enviar el email: ', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
            throw new \Exception("Error al enviar el email", 500);
        }

    }
}

Posterior a esto he creado un componente livewire:
class SendEmailForm extends Component
{
    public $email;
    public $subject;
    public $body;

    //validaciones basicas
    protected $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'body' => 'required|string',
    ];

    // Método para enviar el email
    public function sendEmail(AzureEmailService $azureEmailService)
    {
        // Validamos el formulario antes de enviar
        $this->validate();

        try {
            // Llamamos al servicio Azure para enviar el email
            $azureEmailService->sendEmail($this->email, $this->subject, $this->body);

            // Si el email se envía correctamente, mostramos un mensaje de éxito
            session()->flash('success', 'Email enviado correctamente.');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Si hay un error, lo mostramos
            session()->flash('error', 'Error al enviar el email: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.send-email-form');
    }
}

para conectarlo con la vista que contiene un formulario para el envio de email
<div class="max-w-xl mx-auto p-6 bg-white shadow-md rounded-md">
    @if (session()->has('success'))
        <div class="text-green-500 mb-4">
            {{ session('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if (session()->has('error'))
        <div class="text-red-500 mb-4">
            {{ session('error') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    <form wire:submit.prevent="sendEmail">
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="email" class="block text-gray-700">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" wire:model="email" class="w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm" required>
            @error('email') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="subject" class="block text-gray-700">Asunto:</label>
            <input type="text" id="subject" wire:model="subject" class="w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm" required>
            @error('subject') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="body" class="block text-gray-700">Mensaje:</label>
            <textarea id="body" wire:model="body" class="w-full border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm" rows="4" required></textarea>
            @error('body') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
            Enviar Email
        </button>
    </form>
</div>

Pero al momento de hacer el envió, estoy recibiendo este error:
[2024-10-18 06:22:19] local.ERROR: Error al enviar el email:  {"error":"Client error: `POST https://laravel.unitedstates.communication.azure.com/emails:send?api-version=2021-10-01-preview` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{\"error\":{\"code\":\"Denied\",\"message\":\"Denied by the resource provider.\"}}
"} 

Claramente el error indica que no tengo autorización, pero no entiendo si debo configurar algo mas en el proceso, si crear algun token antes de acceder o algo por el estilo... La documentación para esos casos no es muy clara, para este caso mi conexión va por cURL pero las demas formas que hay es utilizando un package o SDK, entonces por esta razón la información para mi no queda muy claro...
Como realizar correctamente esta conexión? o hay algun paso que me estoy saltando?
Gracias!
